# Issues using PIC18 as an SPI slave

Tags: embedded, pic

I have been working on a PIC18F45k20 running at 16 MHz and using it as an SPI slave.  I find that no matter the SPI clock rate (SCK) from the master I always have to add a significant delay (~64 us) between SPI bytes to avoid SPI collisions or receive overflow.   Without the delay and at very slow SPI clock rates, 95% of the SPI packets will get through without collision or overflow.

Online posts lend me to think that this may be a "feature" of this, and other, PIC18 processors.

1. Have others observed this same slave “feature”?
2. If this is a “feature”, is it found in all PIC18 processors?

I tested the PIC18 without an interrupt with the following:

```
if (SSPSTATbits.BF)
{
  DataIn = SSPBUF;
  SSPBUF = DataOut;
}
```

Also tested using an interrupt and saw the same challenge.

Makes me wonder if it doesn’t truly detect the SPI clock properly.

Comment: Are there any relevant timing diagrams in the SPI chapter of the PIC18F45k20 datasheet/reference manual?

Comment: The most classic SPI issue is clock skew, which can cause many strange errors. Are you absolutely certain that the master and slave are using 1) the same clock polarity and the 2) same clock phase (trigger on clock edge or on edge+delay)?

Comment: I've tested all 4 basic spi configuration. In each case it worked, but in each case it required the lengthy (relatively speaking) inter-transactional delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an oscilloscope check to make sure that the chip select is not being released prior to the PIC clocking out the last SPI data byte. You need to wait on the SPI busy bit before releasing the chip select line.

Answer (score 0):

As I know PIC18 is a 8bit microcontroller, although you can easily find that it's integer variable is mapped into 16bit. However SPI works with 8bit data. It means if your master send for this microcontroller more than 8bit, such as 16 bit, overflow happens in SPI module and cann't response to master clock anymore. So In Slave mode, make sure data from master have 8bit structure. But if pic18 was Master in SPI connection, even though its slave send 16bit data, pic18 hold clock data after first 8bit and wait until its buffer read and empty for next 8bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've also come across this issue and it seems like what one should take into account is that supported SPI simple tells how fast MCU can receive *one* byte into SSPBUF.

Reading this byte from SSPBUF and storing it in a buffer will require some work like incrementing a pointer etc., which will take some time. This is what reduces actual SPI bandwidth for multi-byte SPI.